# Generate class from Xml template to build XPath

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpath, t4

I am wondering if there is already something which generate some c# class from XML template to be able to have a less fragile code using xpath ?

Instead of having an XPATH `"/cat/noeud/key"` building the xpath from the generated classes `Cat.Noeud.Key`

I used something like that for controller in asp.net mvc, curious if someone used something like that for xml templates ?

[EDIT]

I had T4 tag to my question but I didn't elaborated, the purpose is to have a T4.tt which will be regenerated after each recompilation, in order if we have a change in the xml template we will have a compilation error

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to generate classes from a XML definiton look into the tool called xsd.exe ([link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5s2x1sy7(v=vs.110).aspx)).

Provided you have defined an Xml Schema (.xsd file, [link here](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_intro.asp)) representing your XML, xsd.exe can be used to generate classes that match that XML Schema.

An instance of one such class will when serialized (as XML) result in an XML representation of that instance. (Conforming to the XML schema used when generating the classes).

Answer (score 0):

Like Geekiod mentioned I use XSD.  Here's my T4 setup:

I have MyObject.xml file in my T4 solution.

To generate MyObject.cs from MyObject.xml (or update when i make changes to the MyObject.xml schema) I run this bat script:

```
cd C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin
xsd "C:\Users\XXXX\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\XXXXX.Templates\XXXXX.Templates.CodeGenerator\MyObject.xml"
xsd "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin\MyObject.xsd" /c
xcopy /s "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin\MyObject.cs" "C:\Users\XXXXX\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\XXXXX.Templates\XXXXXX.Templates.Common"
```

This runs the XSD program provided by the Microsoft SDK on your .xml file.  XSD generates an .xsd file.  You run XSD again on the new .xsd file and it will create your .cs file.  All with the same name.  The script then copies the .cs file from the SDK folder back into my project.

Now you have your .cs strongly typed file, based off your xml doc.  You can now do cool stuff in your .tt files like this:

```
<#@ parameter name="XmlFileName" type="System.String" #>
<#

    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyObject));
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(this.XmlFileName);
    MyObject O = (MyObject)serializer.Deserialize(sr);

#>
using System;


public class <#= O.Name #> : BusinessObjectBase<<#= O.Name #>Data>
    {
        #region Construction

        private <#= O.Name #>() : base(true) {}

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <#= Utility.GetRefClassName(O.Name) #> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="data"></param>
        <#= Utility.GetRemarksComment2(O) #>
        internal <#= O.Name #>(<#= O.Name #>Data data) : base(data) {}

        #endregion

        #region <#= O.Name #> Data

        <#
        // Generate a property for each child.
        foreach (MyObjectProperty objProp in O.Property)
        {
            if (objProp.GetAccess == "public")
            {
                objProp.GetAccess = ""; 
            }
            else
            {
                objProp.GetAccess = objProp.GetAccess + " ";
            }

            if (objProp.SetAccess == "public")
            {
                objProp.SetAccess = ""; 
            }
            else
            {
                objProp.SetAccess = objProp.SetAccess + " ";
            }

        #>/// <summary>
```

...

To run my T4 solution to generate the code off the .tt files I have the "XmlFileName" variable tied to the TextTemplatingSession class.  This then allows me to point to whatever MyObject.xml file I'd like (MyOtherObject.xml, Customer.xml, etc):

```
static void RunThroughSession()
        {
            string objectName = "MyObject";

            var template = Activator.CreateInstance<BusinessObjectTemplate>();
            TextTemplatingSession session = new TextTemplatingSession();
            session["XmlFileName"] =
                @"C:\Users\XXXXX\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\XXXXXX.Templates\XXXXXX.Templates.CodeGenerator\" + objectName + ".xml";

            template.Session = session;
            template.Initialize();
            string outputText = template.TransformText();
            using (StreamWriter sr = new StreamWriter(
                @"C:\Users\XXXXX\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\XXXXX.Templates\XXXXXX.Templates.CodeGenerator\GeneratedCode\BusinessObject" + objectName + ".cs"))
            {
                sr.Write(outputText);
            }
```

The final piece of this is you need to change the "Custom Tool" option from the .tt file properties to "TextTemplatingFilePreprocessor".  The default is something like "TextTemplatingGenerator" which doesn't work with this setup.

Hope this helps!